# How to Add Lines Depending on File Content (sed)

Tags: sed, makefile

I have a list of files (in a file called `inputlist`) that are located in a couple of subdirectories, similar to this:

```
\input ./bak/dir1/file1
\input ./bak/dir1/file2
\input ./bak/dir2/file1
\input ./bak/dir2/file2
\input ./bak/dir3/file1
\input ./bak/dir3/file2
```

Before each change of directory I want to add a line with `\addcontentsline`. For example the first line should read:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\dir1}
```

I have tried to use `sed` to extract the name of the subdirectory, see below. But then I fail to put everything together.

```
sed -e 's|.*./bak/\(.*\)/.*|\\\1|' inputlist
```

which will return a list of `\dir1` etc.

So I am looking for a `makefile` solution that will help translate my `inputlist` into something like this:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\dir1}
\input ./bak/dir1/file1
\input ./bak/dir1/file2
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\dir2}
\input ./bak/dir2/file1
\input ./bak/dir2/file2
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\dir3}
\input ./bak/dir3/file1
\input ./bak/dir3/file2
```

I have macros defined that will expand to a reasonable line for the table of contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `sed` is suitable to do this.
Try `awk`:

```
awk -F/ -v s='\\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\\' '{if ($3!=dir) {if(dir) print s dir "}" ORS lines; dir=$3; lines=$0;} else lines=lines ORS $0}END{if(dir) print s dir "}" ORS lines}' inputlist
```

I.E.

```
$ cat inputlist
\input ./bak/dir1/file1
\input ./bak/dir1/file2
\input ./bak/dir2/file1
\input ./bak/dir2/file2
\input ./bak/dir3/file1
\input ./bak/dir3/file2

$ awk -F/ -v s='\\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\\' '{if ($3!=dir) {if(dir) print s dir "}" ORS lines; dir=$3; lines=$0;} else lines=lines ORS $0}END{if(dir) print s dir "}" ORS lines}' inputlist
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\dir1}
\input ./bak/dir1/file1
\input ./bak/dir1/file2
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\dir2}
\input ./bak/dir2/file1
\input ./bak/dir2/file2
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\dir3}
\input ./bak/dir3/file1
\input ./bak/dir3/file2
```

This assume the lines are all like that, and the `dir#`'s position are relatively fixed.
If that will change, then the awk command need change accrodingly.

Comment: Thanks for picking up my problem. Using `awk` is fine and, in fact, your solution works if I run it from bash. If I plug it into `make` it somehow fails.
Another thing is that the directory I want to use it on does not have numbered `dir`s, but filenames like these:

Comment: `\input ./bak/corner/1spacenotchercorner.sgf.bak.tex`
`\input ./bak/corner/carpenter.plusone.var1.sgf.bak.tex`

Comment: @fborchers I mean the levels are fixed or not, since my awk command use `/` to separate and pick the subpath name.  Plug in `make`, how do you do it?

Comment: yes, all paths are very similar: `\input ./bak/somedir/somefilename`, especially the `./bak/` is fixed. And yes, there is just this one subdirectory in which the file rests.

Comment: @fborchers  That's ok then. So what do you mean by `plug in make`?

Comment: I use a make file to call your `awk` command. The problem seems to be that `make` uses a different shell: `sh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: @fborchers  I tested on `sh` and it's fine. I guess it's because escaping. Search find this two questions maybe will give you some insights: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445218/why-does-awk-not-work-correctly-in-a-makefile) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382764/escaping-in-makefile).

Comment: @fborchers  In the makefile, replace all `$` in the `awk` command with `$$` first, and check if it's working.