# What does the double dollar sign ($$) mean?

Tags: awk

I simply can't figure out how does this line of awk code work.

```
$$1~/^[^0-9]/ {print $$1;}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be super surprised if this were from a makefile, though.

Comment: The following might be relevant: [Why does AWK not work correctly in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30445218/8344060)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$` sign is an operator in awk to reference a field. Example:

```
$ echo "foo bar car" | awk '{print $2}'
bar
```

This prints `bar`, as `bar` is the content of the second field.

A double dollar sign is actually a double reference that will use the information of the first field reference to get to the other field reference. Example:

```
$ echo "foo bar car 1 2 3" | awk '{print $$5}'
bar
$ echo "foo bar car 1 2 3" | awk '{print $5}'
2
```

Here it prints `bar` as `$5` is dereferenced as `2` and thus `$$5` is equivalent to `$2`

Comment: Ta make it simpler to read/understand, you could use parentheses like this:  `awk '{print $($5)}'`  It will expand the parentheses first, giving `2`, and then you get `$2` that gives `bar`.    `echo "foo 3 car 1 2 3" | awk '{print $$$5}' => car`  or `echo "foo 3 car 1 2 3" | awk '{print $($($5))}' = car`