# How to extract text between first 2 dashes in the string using sed or grep in shell

Tags: regex, shell, sed, makefile, grep

I have the string like this `feature/test-111-test-test`.
I need to extract string till the second dash and change forward slash to dash as well.

I have to do it in Makefile using shell syntax and there for me doesn't work some regular expression which can help or this case

Finally I have to get smth like this:
**input - `feature/test-111-test-test`**
**output - `feature-test-111-` or at least `feature-test-111`**

```
feature/test-111-test-test | grep -oP '\A(?:[^-]++-??){2}' | sed -e 's/\//-/g')
```

But `grep -oP` doesn't work in my case. This regexp doesn't work as well - `(.*?-.*?)-.*`.

Comment: *"`grep -oP doesn't work`"*. Are you sure it was just `grep` that didn't work. The command you posted seems broken, the first part is just a string. I would have expected something like `echo` to print that string. Also, at the end there is a stray `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` keeping in mind that in *Makefile* the `$` char in `awk` command [must be doubled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30445374/3832970):

```sh
url=$(shell echo 'feature/test-111-test-test' | awk -F'-' '{gsub(/\//, "-", $$1);print $$1"-"$$2"-"}')
echo "$url"
# => feature-test-111-
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/IbyWJA). Here, `-F'-'` sets the field delimiter as `-`, `gsub(/\//, "-", $1)` replaces `/` with `-` in Field 1 and `print $1"-"$2"-"` prints the value of `-`-separated Field 1 and 2.

Or, with a regex as a field delimiter:

```sh
url=$(shell echo 'feature/test-111-test-test' | awk -F'[-/]' '{print $$1"-"$$2"-"$$3"-"}')
echo "$url"
# => feature-test-111-
```

The `-F'[-/]'` option sets the field separator to `-` and `/`.

The `'{print $1"-"$2"-"$3"-"}'` part prints the first, second and third value with a separating hyphen.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/kr6G8R).

Comment: Thanks for reply @wiktor-stribiżew. For me it doesn't work properly.         
s='feature/test-111-test-test'
url=$(shell awk -F'[-/]' '{print $1"-"$2"-"$3"-"}' <<< "$s"). I'm getting just 3 hyphens s='feature/test-111-test-test'
url=---

Comment: @VitaliiSotnichenko In Makefile, `$` [is special](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30445374/3832970). You need to double it, so use `url=$(shell awk -F'[-/]' '{print $$1"-"$$2"-"$$3"-"}' <<< "$s")`

Comment: @VitaliiSotnichenko Do my updated solutions work now?

Comment: Yes, it's working now. Do you know by any chance how to add prefix to the beginning of line. I'd like to add http:// but since I  have replacement / to -, http:// changes to http:--. I  have this line so far - echo http://$(s) | awk -F'-' '{gsub(/\//, "-", $$1);print $$1"-"$$2"-"}'

Comment: @VitaliiSotnichenko You can append `http://` in the `print` command, `awk -F'-' '{gsub(/\//, "-", $$1);print "http://"$$1"-"$$2"-"}'` or `awk -F'[-/]' '{print "http://"$$1"-"$$2"-"$$3"-"}'`

Comment: works perfectly for me, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Another `sed` solution using a capture group and regex/pattern iteration (same thing Socowi used):

```
$ s='feature/test-111-test-test'
$ sed -E 's/\//-/;s/^(([^-]*-){3}).*$/\1/' <<< "${s}"
feature-test-111-
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support
- `s/\//-/` - replace `/` with `-`
- `s/^....*$/` - match start and end of input line
- `(([^-]-){3})` - capture group #1 that consists of 3 sets of `anything not -` followed by `-`
- `\1` - print just the capture group #1 (this will discard everything else on the line that's not part of the capture group)

To store the result in a variable:

```
$ url=$(sed -E 's/\//-/;s/^(([^-]*-){3}).*$/\1/' <<< "${s}")
$ echo $url
feature-test-111-
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the `n`th occurrence of a character `C` you don't need fancy perl regexes. Instead, build a regex of the form *"(anything that isn't `C`, then `C`) for `n` times"*:

```
grep -Eo '([^-]*-){2}' | tr / -
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` and `cut`

```
echo feature/test-111-test-test| cut -d'-' -f-2 |sed 's/\//-/'
```

Output

```
feature-test-111
```

---

```
echo feature/test-111-test-test| cut -d'-' -f-2 |sed 's/\//-/;s/$/-/'
```

Output

```
feature-test-111-
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple BRE regex form of *not something then that something* which is `[^-]*-` to get all characters other than `-` up to a `-`.

This works:

```
echo 'feature/test-111-test-test' | sed -nE 's/^([^/]*)\/([^-]*-[^-]*-).*/\1-\2/p'
feature-test-111-
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea using parameter expansions/substitutions:

```
s='feature/test-111-test-test'
tail="${s//\//-}"                   # replace '/' with '-'

# split first field from rest of fields ('-' delimited); do this 3x times

head="${tail%%-*}"                  # pull first field
tail="${tail#*-}"                   # drop first field

head="${head}-${tail%%-*}"          # pull first field; append to previous field
tail="${tail#*-}"                   # drop first field

head="${head}-${tail%%-*}-"         # pull first field; append to previous fields; add trailing '-'

$ echo "${head}"
feature-test-111-
```

Answer (score 0):

A short sed solution, *without* extended regular expressions:

```
sed 's|\(.*\)/\([^-]*-[^-]*\).*|\1-\2|'
```